# Django user registration - email invitations?

Tags: django, django-registration

I am trying to hack my way through the wonderful django-registration app, and add the ability to send email invitations for the site.

The sending of invitations is trivial: the user enters an email, and the view sends an email to the recipient with a random alphanumeric sequence in the activation link.

I largely took the code from Ayman Hourieh's book on Django. The problem is that in the book Ayman develops a custom made registration system, and then adds the variable invitation to the session. **I don't know how to do it with Bennett's django-registration, so that when somebody follows the link, and performs the activation, he can become friend with the user than sent the invitation.** This is crucial for me because I need the ability to track the number of users that each user drove to the site. Anyone had experience with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at django-invitation? It's build on django-registration

http://code.welldev.org/django-invitation/wiki/Home

**EDIT** 
I haven't used it before so I don't know its exact functionality, but looking at the code, when an invitation is sent, [an InvitationKey object](http://code.welldev.org/django-invitation/src/127ac49785f6/invitation/models.py#cl-66) is created which has a `from_user` and `registrant` so the functionality is there whether it's documented or not.

Comment: I think that's just what I needed. Thank you very much sir!

Comment: Only one thing... I just realised that there is no connection established between the sender and the receiver in django-invitation, and this is precisely what I am trying to accomplish...

Comment: I updated my post. The invitations do track who invited who, it might just be a case of figuring out how to make use of that